# Mark/select pages for later extraction

Tags: page, extract

I have a working, fairly complex setup to create a large-ish document (> 200 pages). I would like to create a "preview" of selected parts of the document. There are numerous questions about how to cut and splice the PDF file - this is **not** what I'm asking for.

What I would like to do is

- mark the areas in the document source that I would like to have included in the excerpt - I'm thinking about some kind of `\startpreview` and `\endpreview` commands
- write the pages that these commands would be rendered to if they were text to some external file (or possibly the .aux file if that helps or is easier?) so that I get the page ranges to extract **dynamically**
- assemble either a command line script or some .tex file that extracts the actual preview

I should be able to get the last step together, but I get the feeling that there should be a package or some pre-assembled tool to achieve the first two steps. I haven't been able to find anything. What would be the best way to get the page ranges of the marked areas in the document out into some post-processing tool?

Comment: The `atbegshi` package allows you to discard some pages from the output file. With a little programming one could select which pages stay in the final file and discard the rest. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to mark and identify the pages in the first place. I will have to do some post-processing anyway - resizing, watermarking and so on - so having a secondary run would not be an issue. That being said - combining `atbegshi` with some kind of toggle might work... Just needs a bit of care, because I actually need to capture the page that contains the `\endpreview` command...

Comment: @vwegert: If you have an `TeXLive` (updated) distribution and `Perl` you can use the `ltximg` script is designed for situations like this, you can mark the preview (or extract) sections with `%<*ltximg>..%<*ltximg>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding another answer because the previous one <sub><sup><sub><sup>almost</sup></sub></sup></sub> works and because it is a completely different approach.

I defined the same two commands; `\startpreview` and `\endpreview`.

## Their behavior:

The `\startpreview` macro defines a `\prevpage` macro that holds the current page number. The `\endpreview` macro will complete this page range crating a macro with `start-end`.

The `\startpreview` macro will write this page range to a file `\jobname.prev`.

At the end of the compilation, the file `\jobname.prev` will have the page ranges of the "preview". To create the preview pdf one just have to pass this file to a pdf manager software, like `pdftk`.

For example, with `pdftk` and `bash`, the preview pdf could be created with:

```bash
pdftk main.pdf cat $(cat main.prev) output preview.pdf
```

## The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcounter{globalpage}
\AtBeginDocument{\setcounter{globalpage}{1}}
\AtBeginShipout{\stepcounter{globalpage}}

\newwrite\fid
\immediate\openout\fid=\jobname.prev
\newif\ifprev\prevfalse
\newif\ifstartprev\startprevfalse

\def\removelastpage#1-#2\null{%
  \xdef\prevpage{#1-}%
}
\def\startpreview{%
  \ifstartprev
    \errmessage{You must use \string\endpreview\space before using another \string\startpreview.}
  \fi%
  \startprevtrue%
  \ifprev% one page range was already defined
    \ifnum\lastpage=\the\value{globalpage}% if the last page of the previous range is equal to the first page of this range then they are the same
      \expandafter\removelastpage\prevpage\null%
    \else% otherwise, write
      \immediate\write\fid{\prevpage}%
      \xdef\prevpage{\the\value{globalpage}-}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \xdef\prevpage{\the\value{globalpage}-}%
  \fi
  \prevfalse
}
\def\endpreview{%
  \ifstartprev\else
    \errmessage{You must use \string\startpreview\space before using \string\endpreview.}
  \fi%
  \startprevfalse%
  \xdef\prevpage{\prevpage\the\value{globalpage}}%
  \xdef\lastpage{\the\value{globalpage}}%
  \prevtrue%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \ifstartprev\endpreview\fi% finish preview if necessary
  \immediate\write\fid{\prevpage}%
}

\let\oldthepage\thepage
\renewcommand*\thepage{{\Huge\oldthepage}}
\begin{document}
\Huge

\startpreview
\lipsum[1]
\endpreview

\lipsum[2-5]

\startpreview
\lipsum[6]
\endpreview

\startpreview
\lipsum[7-8]
\endpreview

\end{document}
```

## Update:

The previous version of the code saved `\the\value{page}` to the .prev file. In my naïvety I didn't see the problem in that, but once the code was to be used in, say, a book that contained a table of contents with roman numerals, the saved numbers would be wrong. So I defined a `globalpage` and made it increase with the `\AtBeginShipout` hook, so the number saved in the .prev file is, hopefully, the global page number.

Answer (score 4):

Here it goes :)

I created two macros: `\startpreview` and `\endpreview`.

## Their behavior:

- Everything *after* a `\startpreview` will be written to the output pdf.
- Everything starting from the page after an `\endpreview` will be discarded, unless a `\startpreview` overrides this.

## How they work:

I defined two counters (I couldn't make it work with a `\newif`, for some reason), `\thiskeep` and `\nextkeep`. `\thiskeep` will tell if the *current page* is to be kept, and `\nextkeep` tells if the next one will be kept.

The `\startpreview` macro will set `\thiskeep` and `\nextkeep` to keep the current page and any one that comes after.

The `\endpreview` macro will set `\nextkeep` to discard the next page. But it will do nothing with `\thiskeep`. This is to make `\startpreview` "stronger" than `\endpreview`.

Finally, there is a hook when each page is shipped out that checks if `\thiskeep` is set to 1. If it is not, then the hook discards the page and make `\thiskeep` be `\nextkeep`.

The default behavior is to discard every page.

## The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\newcount\thiskeep\global\thiskeep=0
\newcount\nextkeep\global\nextkeep=0

\def\startpreview{%
  \global\thiskeep=1%
  \global\nextkeep=1%
}
\def\endpreview{%
  \global\nextkeep=0%
}

\AtBeginShipout{%
\ifodd\thiskeep\else%
  \AtBeginShipoutDiscard%
\fi%
\global\thiskeep=\nextkeep%
}

\let\oldthepage\thepage
\renewcommand*\thepage{{\Huge\oldthepage}}
\begin{document}
\Huge

\startpreview
\lipsum[1]
\endpreview

\lipsum[2-5]

\startpreview
\lipsum[6]
\endpreview

\startpreview
\lipsum[7-8]
\endpreview

\end{document}
```

## Output:

Furnishings added to make visualization easy.

Note the missing pages between 2 and 6 :)

[image]

Comment: While this solution looks brilliant, it has an undesired side-effect: it breaks all references to excluded pages. This includes the TOC which I definitely want to include, but since I'm also using fancyref, it completely breaks the build process :-((

Comment: @vwegert Ouch, I didn't realise that. I'll take a look, see if I can solve that. But I don't think that it will be so simple this time :/

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy to get the page ranges written to a separate output file, if I only knew how to do that

Comment: @vwegert See my new answer. I think it might suit your needs.